# Can I use __kindof with protocols in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, generics, casting, covariance

I know I can make use of Objective-C's lightweight generics using the `__kindof` keyword, e.g.

```
NSArray<__kindof BaseClass*> *myArray;
```

This would remove any warnings for assigning any object from the array to a derived class.

However, instead of `BaseClass`, I have `BaseProtocol`, e.g. all my classes in question will conform the `BaseProtocol`, regardless of their base class. I want to use lightweight generics to dictate "my array consists of elements conforming to `BaseProtocol`, but they can be any class".

For example in C#, I can say: `List<IMyInterface>` which would mean that the list consists of elements that implement the `IMyInterface` interface (I know C# has strong generics and Objective-C has only lightweight generics that doesn't prevent compilation, but you get the idea).

Is there any way to achieve this functionality on Objective-C?

E.g. I want to write

```
NSArray<__kindof id<MyProtocol>> //compiles, but as the generic argument is "id", it accepts any object, including invalid ones
```

or

```
NSArray<id<__kindof MyProtocol>> //doesn't compile
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**:

Here is a complete self-contained code:

```
@protocol MyProtocol

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyProtocol>

@end

@implementation MyClass

@end

@interface AnotherClass : NSObject

@end

@implementation AnotherClass

@end



NSMutableArray<__kindof id<MyProtocol>> *myArray;

void test(){
    MyClass *myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    AnotherClass *anotherClassInstance = [[AnotherClass alloc] init];

    myArray = @[].mutableCopy;
    [myArray addObject:myClassInstance];
    [myArray addObject:anotherClassInstance]; //i get warning. good.

    MyClass *returnedInstance = myArray[0];
    AnotherClass *anotherInstance = myArray[1]; //why don't I get a warning here?
}
```

Comment: @Rob right, my bad. fixed. (regarding the second comment)

Comment: @Rob I've implemented an example in a new clean project and as you've said I do get a warning if I try to add an object whose type doesn't conform to the protocol. but even though I'm applying the exact pattern in my main project I'm not getting a warning. I haven't played with any project settings related to warnings. what might be the reason?

Comment: If you go to the "report navigator", you can pull up the log for the compile, and it says that it is a result of `-Wobjc-literal-conversion`. So, go back to your build settings for the first project and search for "literal" and you'll see the setting (called "Implicit Objective-C Literal Conversions"). Perhaps this is an old project that predated these settings.

Comment: @Rob interesting. that option is set to "yes", and in my project I've tried `NSArray<SpecificClass<MyProtocol>*>*` and I do `NSObject *x = myArray[0];` which should now give me warning if I understood correctly, but it doesn't.

Comment: In your last edit, you ask why you don't get a warning on you new `AnotherClass *anotherInstance = myArray[1]` example. I don't see that warning in that particular example, either, but do when I change the `NSArray` declaration to `NSArray<__kindof SpecificClass<MyProtocol>*>*array;` rather than either `NSArray<__kindof NSObject<MyProtocol>*>*array;` or `NSArray<__kindof id MyProtocol>*>*array;`. It strikes me that your example should generate a warning, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is correct:

```
NSArray <__kindof id <MyProtocol>> *array = ...
```

You can also omit `__kindof`, too, and still enjoy lightweight generics. It will still warn you about adding objects of the wrong type even without that keyword. The `__kindof` is used if you want to pull an object out of that array and assign it to a subtype without a cast, but otherwise __kindof is not needed:

```
NSArray <id <MyProtocol>> *array = ...
```

Both of these patterns will warn you if you add an object of a specific type to the array, but that type doesn't conform to `MyProtocol`.

What this won't warn you about is if you try to add an object of type `id` by itself. So avoid using unqualified `id` types within your code and you'll enjoy lightweight generics.

If you're still not seeing the warnings, make sure you have `-Wobjc-literal-conversion` warning turned on. So, go back to your build settings for the first project and search for "literal" and you'll see the setting (called "Implicit Objective-C Literal Conversions").

---

Consider this example:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@end

@interface Foo: NSObject <MyProtocol>
@end

@interface Bar: Foo
@end

@interface Baz: NSObject
@end
```

Then consider:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
Bar *bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
Baz *baz = [[Baz alloc] init];
id   qux = [[Baz alloc] init];

NSArray <id <MyProtocol>> *array1;
array1 = @[foo, bar, baz, qux];           // warning: object of type 'Baz *' is not compatible with array element type 'Foo *'
```

Note, that warns us about `baz`, but not `qux`. So be wary of using `id` types.

```
id <MyProtocol> object1 = array1[0];      // no warning, great
```

So, that's using the protocol as a lightweight generic and it works as expected.

The only reason you'd add `__kindof` is if you wanted to avoid this warning:

```
Foo *foo1 = array1[0];                    // warning: initializing 'Foo *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<MyProtocol> _Nullable'
```

In that case, you'd use `__kindof`:

```
NSArray <__kindof id <MyProtocol>> *array2;
array2 = @[foo, bar, baz];                // again, warning: object of type 'Baz *' is not compatible with array element type 'Foo *'

id <MyProtocol> object2 = array2[0];      // no warning, great

Foo *foo2 = array2[0];                    // no warning, great
```

Comment: okay, I think I've had some misunderstanding about what exactly results in an error. if I use `NSObject<MyProtocol>` instead of `id<MyProtocol>` it becomes more clear. I still don't know why I get that error in clean project but not in my main one though.